libllmodel.dll is missing in gpt4all api llmodel_DO_NOT_MODIFY folder
I have recently switched to LocalClient() (g4f api) class in my app. Therefore I decided to recompile my python script into exe. Pyinstaller showed this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_ctypes.py", line 53, in __init__
  File "ctypes\__init__.py", line 376, in __init__
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI184642\gpt4all\llmodel_DO_NOT_MODIFY\build\libllmodel.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "My_Diary.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter, tkinter.filedialog, tkinter.messagebox, pickle, os, sys, docx, typing, My_Diary_interface, My_Diary_window, CTkMenuBar, locale, CTkMessagebox, My_Diary_converterer, My_Diary_AI, tkterminal, My_Diary_PDF_viewer, asyncio
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "My_Diary_AI.py", line 1, in <module>
    import g4f, g4f.local, typing, My_Diary_AI_interface, asyncio
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "g4f\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "g4f\models.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "g4f\Provider\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "g4f\Provider\Local.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "g4f\locals\provider.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "gpt4all\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "gpt4all\gpt4all.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "gpt4all\_pyllmodel.py", line 71, in <module>
  File "gpt4all\_pyllmodel.py", line 61, in load_llmodel_library
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_ctypes.py", line 55, in __init__
pyimod03_ctypes.install.<locals>.PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI184642\\gpt4all\\llmodel_DO_NOT_MODIFY\\build\\libllmodel.dll'. Most likely this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.

How to fix it?
I dind't do anything. I thought it would work because I had an app with g4f api that worked.

Solved. Just downgrade from gpt4all 2.7.0 to gpt4all 2.6.0
